# Nodejs - unique string of 512 length

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to generate a unique string with 512 characters in length.

Can i use nodejs built-in crypto module to generate a unique string and have least collision.

Can the below sample achieve it

```
crypto.randomBytes(512, (err, buf) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(`${buf.length} bytes of random data: ${buf.toString('hex')}`);
});
```

Comment: Read the docs about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your requirement is to have 512 characters from `0-9` and `a-f`, then yes it should gives you a decently random value. Based on the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptorandombytessize-callback):

> Generates cryptographically strong pseudorandom data. The size argument is a number indicating the number of bytes to generate.

However, if your requirement is to generate 512 characters of any kind (eg. uppercase letters, `g-z`, symbols etc), then you might want to try other `.toString` method such as `utf8` or `base64`, which you can read more from the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buftostringencoding-start-end)

Comment: .toString('utf8') results in malformed string result. will the base64 result in unique string or can i use the .toString('hex')

Comment: `base64` should generates you a string that is [URL safe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) (Supported characters: `0-9`, `A-Z`, `a-z`, `+/=`). However, do note that since it can represent 64 possibilities in 1 character (whereas only 2^4 = 16 in a byte), the actual length you obtained will be less than 512 characters.